# How Netty uses thread pools?

Tags: java, netty

Can you please explain how Netty uses thread pools to work? Do I understand correctly, that there are two kinds of thread-pools: boss and worker. Boss ones are used to do I/O and worker are used to call user callbacks (messageReceived) to process data?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

This is from NioServerSocketChannelFactory document

> A ServerSocketChannelFactory which
>   creates a server-side NIO-based
>   ServerSocketChannel. It utilizes the
>   non-blocking I/O mode which was
>   introduced with NIO to serve many
>   number of concurrent connections
>   efficiently.
>
> How threads work
>   There are two types
>   of threads in a
>   NioServerSocketChannelFactory; one is
>   boss thread and the other is worker
>   thread.
>
> Boss threads
>   Each bound
>   ServerSocketChannel has its own boss
>   thread. For example, if you opened two
>   server ports such as 80 and 443, you
>   will have two boss threads. A boss
>   thread accepts incoming connections
>   until the port is unbound. Once a
>   connection is accepted successfully,
>   the boss thread passes the accepted
>   Channel to one of the worker threads
>   that the NioServerSocketChannelFactory
>   manages.
>
> Worker threads
>   One
>   NioServerSocketChannelFactory can have
>   one or more worker threads. A worker
>   thread performs non-blocking read and
>   write for one or more Channels in a
>   non-blocking mode.

In Nio model, bossThread take care all bounded socket(listen socket), workerThread take care Accepted-socket (included IO and call event method such as messageReceived).

Comment: This is how I understand as well. However, in all examples of Netty, I see setting the boss pool with a cachedThreadPool. Why not use a singleThreadExecutor? Is there any specific reason to it? Asking this question in this thread instead of a new one, to be very to the point and since this discussion has already been raised.

Answer (score 18):

Description related to Netty Nio implementation (3.2.4.Final) NioServerSocketChannelFactory.

**The worker thread pool** has to be able to deliver at least Number of Workers threads (currently default 2*number of cores).

Why?

In case of this implementation each worker has his own selector loop, this means that each worker will "eat up" one thread to sleep on the selector. Also that worker (and associated thread) is responsible for doing all the actual writes and reads (including fireing events on the pipeline, that means handlers are executed in that workers thread).

**In case of the boss** thread pool, actually the thread pool is unneeded because current implementation acquires only a single thread from it. That thread sleeps on the selector for server socket most of the time, after accepting connection that connection is registered with a worker. From that moment on worker is responsible for serving that connection.

Comment: Why is the implementation defaulted to use `2 * number of cores`? How can one core service two threads?