# How does netty allocate worker thread to new request?

Tags: java, netty, nio, worker

In netty I create a channel factory as follows.

> ChannelFactory factory =
>           new NioServerSocketChannelFactory(
>               Executors.newCachedThreadPool(threadFactory),
>               Executors.newCachedThreadPool(threadFactory);

When a new request comes, how does the boss thread allocate a free worker thread to the new request from the workerthread pool? In which netty class can I find this logic?

Answer (score 1):

You can find the logic in **NioServerBoss.class**. Following is part of the netty source code.

```
   for (;;) {
      SocketChannel acceptedSocket = channel.socket.accept();
      if (acceptedSocket == null) {
          break;
      }
      registerAcceptedChannel(channel, acceptedSocket, thread);
   }
```

Part of registerAcceptedChannel:

```
NioWorker worker = parent.workerPool.nextWorker();
worker.register(new NioAcceptedSocketChannel(
        parent.getFactory(), pipeline, parent, sink
        , acceptedSocket,
        worker, currentThread), null);
```

The worker thread will check its taskQueue and run this new task.

Answer (score 0):

see here

Boss threads
Each bound ServerSocketChannel has its own boss thread.

A boss thread accepts incoming connections until the port is unbound.
Once a connection is accepted successfully, 
the boss thread passes the accepted Channel to one of the worker threads that the NioServerSocketChannelFactory manages.

from [How Netty uses thread pools?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5474372/how-netty-uses-thread-pools)

and now some thing will be improve

[netty-issues-240](https://github.com/netty/netty/issues/240)