# configure netty to only have one selector thread?

Tags: netty

We are trying to debug a very nasty issue that appears to happen on netty 3.6.0, 3.6.7 and 3.8.0 on linux and MAC so far.  We can reproduce it pretty well(not extremely easy but pretty well).

What happens is we open a web page which then results in chrome sending around 15 requests for css files, js files, etc. etc.

One of the requests from chromes always hangs.  Digging in deeper, we see the request reach the server in wireshark, but we never see the request come into the playframework server.  All the other requests come in fine.

We literally have to fiddle around with websockets to get it into this weird state(not sure if something around websockets in netty is screwed up or not).

We would like to configure the netty pool to only have ONE worked thread to simplify debugging and see if the issue goes away.  Is it possible to configure the number of threads running on the selector?

This post [How Netty uses thread pools?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5474372/how-netty-uses-thread-pools) looks like it suggested executors upstream which is not what I want.

thanks,
Dean

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass "1" in the the NioServerSocketChannelFactory constructor as last argument.